# Django - Adding index_together when iexact is used in filter

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, indexing

I am creating a index on 2 columns (that can be found in [Django-index together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/)

`index_together = [["name", "value"]]` but I also want it to be case insensitive, because one of my filters will use `iexact`. Any idea how this can be achieved?

I am using latest version of Django with DRF.

I am basically just looking to add a index on those 2 columns that is case insensitive. Don't mind doing a raw SQL query in migration as well if no other way is possible, so raw SQL is also helpful. Just want to make sure that there isn't a native way of doing this

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: I am using Django 3.1.1

Comment: [Functional indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/indexes/#expressions) are supported in Django 3.2 (the latest Django version is 3.2.2). But the support also depends on your database (and version) - see the docs.